# How to eliminate the delay in message redirection to a file in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have this line in my vimrc:

```
redir! >/Users/seanmackesey/.vim/.vimmessages
```

But messages do not show up in this file immediately after they are generated-- when I run `tail -f .vimmessages` in the shell, messages show up slowly and somewhat erratically. I get a big dump of messages to it *sometimes* when I run the `:messages` command, but I can't figure out exactly what the pattern is.  Is there a way to simply append each message as it occurs, immediately, to the end of a file?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with a global `:redir` is that it doesn't nest, so it'll cause errors with mappings and functions that use `:redir`, too. Rather, use

```
:set verbosefile=/Users/seanmackesey/.vim/.vimmessages
```

to capture all messages. Because Vim's implementation uses buffered output, you'd still experience some amount of chunking, though.

You didn't mention where you intend to use this output, so it's hard to give a better recommendation. If you really need immediate output to an external file, you'd have to use `writefile()` or use an embedded scripting language to write and flush a file.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, good to know about `redir`.  My intention is to use the output as a console for debugging.  I'd like to have it open as a split or in a neighboring shell window when testing functions.  The `:messages` command always opens at the top of the list and in a buffer that I can't figure out how to split (just says "press ENTER or type command to continue", and doing either closes it)

Comment: Have a look at Chip's [Decho plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=120). Haven't used it, but it allows to view the messages side-by-side and other fancy stuff. For me, temporarily inserting `:echomsg` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed more likely to be simple data buffering, not any specific time delay.

I grepped through the Vim 7.3 source, and it looks like the `redir` is done with *fopen*, *puts*, and *putc*, and *fclose* (i.e. stdio). There did not appear to be any calls to *fflush*, *setbuf*, *setbuffer*, *setlinebuf*, or *setvbuf* so the redirection will always use the default buffering provided by your system’s stdio (probably “block buffering” of some convenient size).

You could periodically stop and restart the redirection to effectively flush the data:

```
redir END | redir! >>~/.vim/.vimmessages
```

Short of that, there does not seem to be a nice way to do what you want with `redir` to a file.

Comment: Hmmm I may end up implementing the start/stop in a wrapper function to generate debug messages.  Thanks